# If $X$ is an element of a $\sigma$-algebra, and $Y$ is a subset of $X$, must $Y$ be in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $A$ is a sigma algebra, and $X$ is an element of $A$. If $Y$ is a subset of $X$, is $Y$ also an element of $A$?

Comment: The whole space is always in the algebra, so this would imply that every sigma algebra is the full power set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{a,b,c\}$. Find a $\sigma$-algebra on $S$ that has four elements. You can then find $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\in A$ and $Y\subset X$, but $Y\notin A$.

**If** you make an effort to follow this hint and still need help, mouse over the gray box below.

> One such $\sigma$-algebra is $A=\{\varnothing,\{a,b\},\{c\},S\}$.

Comment: So I think A={empty set,{c},{a,b},{a,b,c}} satisfies the definition of a sigma algebra of S, and {a} is a subset of {a,b} which is not in A. so the answer would be no...

Comment: which is the same as your grey box...thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Let  $\mathcal B$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb R$, and take $X$ as the Cantor set then you can find  a subset $Y$ of the Cantor set which is not Borel (this follows from a cardinality argument).

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. The simplest example, perhaps, is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra on a set of more than one element. Another would be the countable/co-countable $\sigma$-algebra on an uncountable set.